# .NET MAUI, CI Build, Fails -> error APT2113: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature

Tags: apk, maui

**I am migrating a Xamarin project to .NET Maui and all of the application is building and running fine locally. But when I try to build it through a CI pipeline in DevOps , I get the Following error in the Build step of the YAML**

```
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/\_temp/c00c6495-9ac3-457b-9f2e-3e8b2d23566e.sh
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.


/Users/runner/work/1/s/project/obj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/logout.png : error APT2113: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/projectobj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/logout.png : error APT2261: file failed to compile. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/project/obj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/receiver.png : error APT2113: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/projectobj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/receiver.png : error APT2261: file failed to compile. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/project/obj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/clear.png : error APT2113: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/project/obj/Release/net7.0-android/resizetizer/r/drawable/clear.png : error APT2261: file failed to compile. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/proj.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
```

This is my Yaml for Build step:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: 'Build project'
      inputs:
        script: |
          dotnet publish $(app-path-project) -c Release -f $(app-target-framework-android) /p:ApplicationId=$(app-id-android)
```

The Solution Builds Fine with Release configuration Locally and I am pretty sure the PNG files are not corrupt and are actual PNG Files.

Thank you for any kind of help :)

I am trying to Release an APK to app center and this is the only step failing

Comment: Please open one of the PNG files in a hex editor and check the first 4 bytes. If should start with `89 50 4e 47` in hex.

Comment: Yes I have done that, And They are actual pngs. Still cannot able to work around it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the file in an image editor to confirm if it's a valid PNG file or convert it to a proper PNG file.
It's likely a JPG renamed to a PNG file, not an actual PNG file. In this situation change extension to the real one and convert to PNG ,then retry.

For instance, you have `logo.png`, but it's actually a JPG image.
You should rename it back to `logo.jpg` and use something like `Photoshop` to convert the image to PNG format.

If none of these solutions work, you can try to rename the extension of your image into `.jpg` instead of `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with Azure DevOps when building the Android version of my application.
The root cause was the following in my *.gitattributes* file:

`* text eol=lf`

This would cause the PNG signature to be altered from

`89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` to `89 50 4E 47 0A 1A 0A`

The `0D` carriage return was removed causing the PGN signature and the file to be invalid.

The fix was to change the *.gitattributes* line above to

`* test eol=auto`

and appending the following line to explicitly treat PNG files as binary:

`*.png binary`